# Second partial derivative problem where a function z = f(y/x) is differentiated

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've been studying partial derivatives and came across this problem:

If $z=f(\frac yx)$ show that $$x^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} + 2xy \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} + y^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = 0$$

I differentiated each of the three second order derivatives applying the chain rule and got:

(Where $u=f(\frac yx)$ and $v = \frac yx$)

- A: $x^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2} = x^2\frac \partial{\partial x} (\frac {\partial u}{\partial v} \frac {\partial v}{\partial x}) = \frac {2y}x \frac {\partial u}{\partial v} - y \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial v}$
- B: $y^2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2} = y^2\frac \partial{\partial y} (\frac {\partial u}{\partial v} \frac {\partial v}{\partial y}) = \frac {y^2}x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial v \partial y}$
- C: $2xy \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y} = 2xy \frac {\partial}{\partial x}(\frac 1x \frac {\partial u}{\partial v}) = - \frac {2y}x \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} + 2y\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial v \partial x}$

The first terms of A and C cancel out, but then I'm left with $$2y\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial v \partial x} + \frac {y^2}x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial v \partial y} - y \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial v}$$

What I'd like to know is whether I got something wrong in my differentiation or if there's some sort of way to turn $\frac {y^2}x \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial v \partial y}$ into $- y \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial v \partial x}$

Comment: Your system $(u,v)$ is not a change of variables.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I used Leibniz notation for the chain rule as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Comment: But here, your function depends on two variables.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac 1yf'(v)$$
$$\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{y^2}f''(v)$$

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac{x}{y^2}f'(v)$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y}=-\frac{1}{y^2}f'(v)-\frac{x}{y^3}f''(v)$$

$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}=\frac{2x}{y^3}f'(v)+\frac{x^2}{y^4}f''(v)$$

Comment: Sorry, I got the y and the x mixed up in the title and in the initial statement of the problem. The working's was done with f = y/x and that was what was originally stated in the problem.

Comment: @user1534513 Your formula is symetric. So $z=f(x/y)$ or $z=f(y/x)$ doesn't change the formula.